Finding series equation solution with analytic data
Consider the equation:
$$ g(t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-n^2 t} a_n, $$
where $ g(t) $ is an analytic function on $[0,T]$ with $ g(0) = 0 $. I want to know if there exist $a_n$, $n\geq 1$ such that this equation has solution. It is clear that the series is analytic which makes the analyticity assumption on $g$ natural. I've tried Laplace transform but without success. Any ideas guys?.
Thank you in advance.
